# How do I get the length of held list without evaluating the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, hold

I used `Extract` with `Hold` to retrieve a sublist containing expressions I didn't want evaluating, *e.g.*

```
foo = Extract[OwnValues[test], {1, 2}, Hold]
(* Hold[{expr1, expr2, expr3}] *)
```

I'm sorry to ask such a trivial question, but, how do I get the length of that list?

Obviously `Length@foo` returns `1` because the top-level head is `Hold`. But attempting to access the lower levels seems to cause evaluation one way or another. What technique am I missing?

Comment: Use `Unevaluated` instead of `Hold` or obtain expression where each list entry is wrapped in `Hold`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test = Hold[{Print@2; 1, 2, 3}];
```

One of many ways would be

```
test /. Hold[l_List] :> Length@Unevaluated@l
```

A couple others

```
Function[l, Length@Unevaluated@l, HoldAll] @@ test
test /. Hold[{args___}] :> Length@Hold[args]
```

Comment: Ah, I see. As @Wizard was saying, I was trying to use `Unevaluated`, but my attempts would evaluate too _little_. Substitution's what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @acheong87, if you'll do it more than once, you could create a function using your own idea of `Extract`, such as `lengthAt[expr_, pos_] := 
 Extract[expr, pos, Function[l, Length@Unevaluated@l, HoldAll]]`. Then, `lengthAt[test, 1]`