# Fall through multiple statements in Switch[]

Tags: conditional, coding-style

Is there a nice way in Mathematica to express the equivalent of Switch where statements (not cases) fall through?  Here is a toy example in C:

```
switch (n)
{
  case 4: printf ("4");
  /* fall through */
  case 3: printf ("3");
  /* fall through */
  case 2: printf ("2");
  /* fall through */
  case 1: printf ("1");
  break;
}
```

(In reality the statements would be computations, not just printf's.)

I've thought of two ways.  One is to use Goto[] and Label[]:

```
ClearAll[trial1];

trial1[n_] := Module[
  {one, two, three, four},
  Goto[{one, two, three, four}[[n]]];
  
  Label[four];
  Print[4];
  
  Label[three];
  Print[3];
  
  Label[two];
  Print[2];
  
  Label[one];
  Print[1];
]
```

The other holds each statement in a list, takes the desired elements, and releases the holds:

```
ClearAll[trial2];

trial2[n_] := Module[
  {lst},
  lst = {
    Hold[Print[4];],
    Hold[Print[3];],
    Hold[Print[2];],
    Hold[Print[1];]
    };
  ReleaseHold[Take[lst, -n]];
]
```

Both work, but neither seems "clean" or Mathematica-like.

My question differs from [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96451/fall-through-multiple-cases-in-switch-to-execute-same-function) where several cases fall through to the same statement.

Added later:  Here is a sample.  Calling the function with 3 results in the last three statements executing.

```
trial2[3]
```

(*
3
2
1
*)

Comment: Doesn't Which[ ] do what you are asking?

Comment: @BillS Documentation says that Which[] returns the value of the *first* test that evaluates True, not every subsequent value too.

Answer (score 2):

I recall once someone defending Mathematica's `Switch[]` not falling through, perhaps as less bug-prone as C's `switch()`. I can't recall what they recommended to do instead.

Here's a way to present the code blocks, even give them helpful names (other than `"A"`, `"B"` etc. that I use below), and execute them conditionally in whatever order. While the C `switch()` is a perhaps a glorified assembly branch,
this is basically an implementation of a C switch table (AFAIR) with a slight -- perhaps only very slight -- Mathematica flair. It also allows more general execution patterns than "fall-through," which was allowed in C because it was easy to implement in assembly language.

I took the OP's question to be general, not the specific, overly symmetric pattern in the example.  That is, my solution may be applied to more complicated switch cases than a sequence of positive integers less than some value for `n`.

```
exec = <|   (* code texts *)
   "A" :> Print["Code 1"],
   "B" :> Print["Code 2"],
   "C" :> Print["Code 3"],
   "D" :> Print["Code 4"]|>;
switch = {  (* switch table with fall-through defined by lists *)
   4 -> {"D", "C", "B", "A"}, (* keys to code texts to be executed *) 
   3 -> {"C", "B", "A"},
   2 -> {"B", "A"},
   1 -> {"A"},
   _ :> Throw[$Failed]}; (* optional `default` *)
nn = 4;
Scan[exec, Replace[nn, switch], 1]
(*
  Code 4
  Code 3
  Code 2
  Code 1
*)
```

I think `Scan` and `Replace` are expressive of the intention. `Replace` will fail if `nn` does not have an appropriate value, even if there is no `default` case -- that is, it will leave `nn` unchanged if there is no `default`. `ReplaceAll` may be used instead -- the operator `/.` is convenient -- but it might replace parts of `nn` if it has integer parts. If bad input is a possibility, then `Replace` might be safer.

```
nn = 3;
Scan[exec, nn /. switch, 1]
(*
  Code 3
  Code 2
  Code 1
*)
```

One reason for using a list instead of an association for the `switch` is that the keys can be patterns. This also shows that the order of the code texts can be arbitrary.

```
switch2 = {
   4 | 3 -> {"D", "C", "B"}, (* pattern key *)
   2 -> {"B", "C"},  (* reversed order - can't be done in C *)
   1 -> {"A"}
   _ :> Throw[$Failed]};     (* optional `default` *)
nn = 3;
Scan[exec, Replace[nn, switch2], 1]
(*
  Code 4
  Code 3
  Code 2
*)
```

Here's the shortest way to type a workaround:

```
nn = 2;
nn /. switch2 /. exec
(*
  Code 2
  Code 3
  Out[]= {Null, Null}
*)
```

Comment: Another way to do the simpler example in the OP, bypassing the `switch` table: `Scan[exec, Take[{"D", "C", "B", "A"}, -nn]]`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `trial2` gets pretty close. This seems more idiomatic:

```
SetAttributes[trial3, HoldRest];
trial3[n_, list_] := Take[Unevaluated@list, -n]

trial3[3, {Echo[4], Echo[3], Echo[2], Echo[1]}]

(* >> 3 *)
(* >> 2 *)
(* >> 1 *)
(* {3,2,1} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer subsequently deleted by @Nassar started me thinking about a function whose argument indicates which individual statement.  That function can be invoked multiple times by Scan[]ing a list:

```
ClearAll[trial3];

trial3[n_] := Scan[
  Switch[#,
    1, Print["1"],
    2, Print["2"],
    3, Print["3"],
    4, Print["4"]
    ] &,
   Take[{4, 3, 2, 1}, -n]
  ]
```

I'm interested in other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

We could implement that style of `Switch` with `Label` and `Goto`:

```
ClearAll[cSwitch];
SetAttributes[cSwitch, HoldAllComplete];

cSwitch::OddCases = 
  "cSwitch called with `1` arguments. cSwitch must be called with an odd number of arguments.";

cSwitch[value_, pairs__] := 
 Module[{cases = HoldComplete[{pairs}], casesLength, begin, n = 1, matchFlag = False, lastValue},
  
  casesLength = cases /. HoldComplete[a_] :> Length[Unevaluated[a]];
  
  Block[{Break = Return},
   If[OddQ[casesLength], Message[cSwitch::OddCases, casesLength + 1]; 
    Return[Defer[cSwitch[value, pairs]]],

    Label[begin];

    If[matchFlag || MatchQ[value, Extract[cases, {1, n}, ReleaseHold]], 
     matchFlag = True; lastValue = Extract[cases, {1, n + 1}, ReleaseHold]];

    If[n < casesLength - 1, n += 2; Goto[begin], Return[lastValue]];
    ]
   ]]
```

Use it as just like `Switch`. It will execute all the cells after it finds a successful match until `Break[]` was called or reach the end, like `C`/`Java`. Also, if you use `Break[1]`, `1` will be returned (ignore the red color).

### Example

Consider this function:

```
ClearAll[dummyFn];
dummyFn[n_] := 
  cSwitch[n, 1, Print[1]; 1,
             2, Print[2], 
             3, Print[3]; Break[],
             4, Print[4]; 4,
             _, Print[Infinity]; -1
];
```

Test:

```
dummyFn[1]

(* Print 1 *)
(* Print 2 *)
(* Print 3 *)

(* Return Null *)
```

```
dummyFn[4]

(* Print 4 *)
(* Print Infinity *)

(* Return -1 *)
```

```
dummyFn[5]

(* Print Infinity *)

(* Return -1 *)
```

Thanks to [@jojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) for his answer in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43016/77079).